# Calling a Scalar Function from SubSonic

Tags: subsonic, user-defined-functions

I've got a SQL Server function that returns a scalar BIT value and takes one parameter. The following gives you an idea:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[fnTest] (@StringToTest VARCHAR(10)) 
RETURNS BIT 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @b BIT 
    IF @StringToTest = 'A' SET @b = 0 ELSE SET @b = 1
    RETURN (@b) 
END
GO
```

Being very new (days!) to SubSonic - how would I call this using SubSonic?

(I'm using a web site with the basic "subsonic.abp" file with an asterisk in it).

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Here's how in VB:

```
Return New SubSonic.InlineQuery().ExecuteScalar(Of Boolean)("SELECT dbo.[fnTest](@StringToTest)", StringToTest)
```

Thanks all, hope this helps someone else,

Thomas

Comment: or `CodingHorror()` instead of `InlineQuery()` if he uses subsonic 3